# Python: Index slicing from a list for each index in for loop

Tags: python, data-structures

I got stuck in slicing from a list of data inside a for loop.

```
list = ['[init.svc.logd]: [running]', '[init.svc.logd-reinit]: [stopped]']
```

what I am looking for is to print only key without it values (running/stopped)

Overall code,

```
for each in list:
    print(each[:]) #not really sure what may work here
```

result expected:

```
init.svc.logd
```

anyone for a quick solution?

Comment: Have you tried `[val.split(':')[0][1:-1] for val in lst]`?

Comment: Main point: You have no key! You have a string that you have to parse/modify according to some rules to get the text you want.

Comment: You have a list of strings. What do you mean by 'key'?

Answer (score 0):

If you want print only the key, you could use the `split` function to take whatever is before `:` and then replace `[` and `]` with nothing if you don't want them:

```
list = ['[init.svc.logd]: [running]', '[init.svc.logd-reinit]: [stopped]']

for each in list:
    print(each.split(":")[0].replace('[','').replace(']','')) #not really sure what may work here
```

which gives :

```
init.svc.logd
init.svc.logd-reinit
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using a regular expression. The concept of 'key' in the question is ambiguous as there are no data constructs shown that have keys - it's merely a list of strings. So...

```
import re

list_ = ['[init.svc.logd]: [running]', '[init.svc.logd-reinit]: [stopped]']

for e in list_:
    if r := re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', e):
        print(r[0])
```

**Output:**

```
init.svc.logd
init.svc.logd-reinit
```

**Note:**

This is more robust than string splitting solutions for cases where data are unexpectedly malformed